# What does JS join/split trick do?

Tags: javascript

I seen this code

```
a=a.join("").split("");
```

What does this code do? I think a was a string array, but is it still a string array? does this filter out values? what does it do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a` is still a string array, but is an array of characters.

```
                   a == ["foo", "", "", "bar", "baz"]
          a.join("") == "foobarbaz"
a.join("").split("") == ["f", "o", "o", "b", "a", "r", "b", "a", "z"]
```

I don't know the purpose of this code.

Answer (score -1):

it creates a copy of the array, dunno why it is assigned to the same variable

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is incorrect. It does more than just copy the array, as described in KennyTM's post.